# Is it possible to expose Rollup library in a variable?

Tags: javascript, webpack, rollup, rollupjs, vite

Is it possible to expose Rollup library in a variable like this one:

```
var libName=function(e){var t={};function n(r){if(t[r])return t[r].exports;var o=t[r]={i:r,l:!1,exports:{}};[...]
```

I'm trying to port some legacy webpack app (ejected create-react-app with `output.library.type = 'var'`) to Rollup, but I can't find appropriate option in rollup docs.

- [output.library.type in Webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#type-var)

My Rollup/Vite config looks like this:

```
export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  process.env = {
    ...process.env,
    ...loadEnv(mode, process.cwd())
  };

  return {
    base: process.env.VITE_BASE_URL,
    build: {
      rollupOptions: {
        preserveEntrySignatures: 'strict',
        input: {
          [Entry.ENTRY_1]: path.resolve(__dirname, `src/${Entry.ENTRY_1}.ts`),
          [Entry.ENTRY_2]: path.resolve(__dirname, `src/${Entry.ENTRY_2}.ts`)
        },
        output: [
          {
            format: 'system',
            entryFileNames
          },
          {
            format: 'module',
            entryFileNames
          },
          // any of these expose as var moduleName = ... like webpack does
          {
            format: 'amd',
            name: 'moduleName',
            entryFileNames
          },
          {
            format: 'commonjs',
            name: 'moduleName',
            entryFileNames
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    plugins: [react(), mode === 'production' && viteExternalsPlugin(sharedDependency)]
  };
});
```

Comment: can you share your rollup configuration?

Comment: Sure. Config is super simple. I thing I need to add new output commonjs compiled to ES5, but still, don't know, how to expose this new module as `var`.

Comment: I think if you want to output your entry point as lib, you might need to output as `umd` module and also give us a name https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputname which is similar to `webpack`.

Comment: `umd` in rollup doesn't support code-splitting. Anyway I can bundle it as `amd` common `commonjs`, but any of these expose module as variable like webpack doeas.

Comment: Setting the `format: 'iife'` should solve your problem.

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem, did you find anything usefull ??